# Java Reflection of 2d arrays

Tags: java, arrays, reflection

I am attempting to reflect a 2d array(which I know the dimensions of), I currently have this code which only returns null with arrays(but works with ints).

```
int[][] currentMap = null;
Maps.class.getField("map" + Player.getPlayerM()).get(currentMap);
```

I'm hoping there is a way I could create a loop but could not find a way to do it. Another of way of putting it I was wondering if I could grab only a part of the array(1 int) then I could loop that to set my new array.

Here's the array its simple:

```
public static int[][] map0 = {{0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0}};
```

Comment: What class is `Maps`? This more than likely is not doing what you think

Comment: I am not sure what are you trying to do. Could you add more details?

Comment: `get` returns something, it doesn't modify the passed in parameter (not to mention the fact that, under no circumstances, can a function change which object one of the passed parameters points to, thus, after the function call, it will always be `null`).